# Integral points on elliptic curve and the Lee norm

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, diophantine-equations, finite-fields, norms

This question is based on small experiments I have done in Sagemath and if it is not research level, I will move it to MSE:

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve defined with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$.

The Lee-norm is

$$|x|_p = \min(x \mod (p),p-x \mod (p))$$

The idea is to use the Lee-norm to identify an integral points given points in finite fields.

If the curve has an integral point $P=(x,y)$ then the reduction modulo good large primes $p,q$ will
be

$$ (|x|_p , |y|_p)=(|x|_q , |y|_q) $$

, since for large primes we will have $|x|_p = x = |x|_q$.

Consider the set

$$S_p := \{(|x|_p, |y|_p) | (x,y) \in E(\mathbb{F}_p)\}$$

Then if the curve $E$ has one integral point $P=(x,y)$ , for all large but finitely many consecutive primes $p,q$ we will have:

$$\emptyset \neq \{(|x|_p, |y|_p)\} \subset S_p \cap S_q$$

Conversely, if for all large consecutive primes $p,q$ we have

$$S_p \cap S_q = \emptyset$$

then the elliptic curve can not have an integral point.

Do you think this idea could be refined to give a practical criterion for testing of integral points?

**Edit**:
If $2|x|<p, 2|x|<q$, then:

$$S_p \cap S_q \neq \emptyset$$

If we have two primes $p_{1}<p_{2}$ such that:

$$S_{p_{1}} \cap S_{p_{2}} = \emptyset$$

then each potential integral point must satisfy:

$$2|x| > p_{1}$$